# ICEPDF hide pagenav , last page and first page

Tags: java, pdf, javafx, fxml, icepdf

I worked to show pdf in javafx with icepdf libraries.Everything success,but ı don't want to see 'First Page' and 'Last Page' buttons in toolbar.API docs show how to hide page navigator completely.

```
        propertiesManager.setBoolean("application.toolbar.show.pagenav", false);
```

I wanna remove only 'First Page' and 'Last Page' buttons.Anyone help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't a configuration option to hide individual navigation buttons.  But it's fairly easy to override the SwingViewBuilder method buildPageNavigationToolBar().

Using the example http://anonsvn.icesoft.org/repo/icepdf/branches/icepdf-6.2.0/icepdf/examples/component/ViewerComponentExample.java you can alter the call:

```
SwingViewBuilder factory = new SwingViewBuilder(controller, properties);
```

to look like this:

```
SwingViewBuilder factory = new SwingViewBuilder(controller, properties){
    @Override
    public JToolBar buildPageNavigationToolBar() {
        JToolBar toolbar = new JToolBar();
        commonToolBarSetup(toolbar, false);
        addToToolBar(toolbar, buildPreviousPageButton());
        addToToolBar(toolbar, buildCurrentPageNumberTextField());
        addToToolBar(toolbar, buildNumberOfPagesLabel());
        addToToolBar(toolbar, buildNextPageButton());
        return toolbar;
    }
};
```

Comment: Tnx a lot :) it works and I added new customizations with overriding.

Answer (score 0):

thanks @pcorless to hide print and save buttons use

```
SwingViewBuilder factory = new SwingViewBuilder(controller, properties){
public JToolBar buildUtilityToolBar(boolean embeddableComponent, PropertiesManager propertiesManager) {
                JToolBar toolbar = new JToolBar();
                commonToolBarSetup(toolbar, false);
                // if embeddable component, we don't want to create the open dialog, as we
                // have no window manager for this case.
                if (PropertiesManager.checkAndStoreBooleanProperty(propertiesManager, PropertiesManager.PROPERTY_SHOW_UTILITY_SEARCH))
                    addToToolBar(toolbar, buildSearchButton());
                if (PropertiesManager.checkAndStoreBooleanProperty(propertiesManager, PropertiesManager.PROPERTY_SHOW_UTILITY_UPANE))
                    addToToolBar(toolbar, buildShowHideUtilityPaneButton());

                // Don't bother with this toolbar if we don't have any visible buttons
                if (toolbar.getComponentCount() == 0) {
                    return null;
                }

                return toolbar;
            }
});
```